# Creating a unique variable for data

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Hi guys so i have created a simple comment box for my site now. It works perfectly, however the problem i am having is that i have different pages which are going to require different comment box. I cant seem to figure out how to get the comment box to be unique for every page. So right now my database holds this :

```
Called comments: 
id 
comment
comment1
comment_date
```

Now my idea is that everything was stored into comment, so i added comment1 for other page to store the info. However i have no clue how to edit the php file to get it to work with comment1. Any help on this would be great.

HTML:

```
<div class="comment_container">
    <div class="comments">
        <?php
            include_once("comments.php");
        ?>
    </div>
        <div class="comments_form">
        <table>
        <tr><td><textarea id="comment_text"></textarea></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="comment_process" value="Post Comment"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#comment_process').click(function() {
            if ($('#comment_text').val() != "") {
                $.post("comments.php?action=post", {
                    comment: $('#comment_text').val()
                }, function(data) {
                    $('.comments').html(data);
                    $('#comment_text').val("");
                });
            }
        });
          });
```

PHP:

```
include_once("connect.php");

function convert ($date) {
    $converteddate = date("F j, Y g:ia", strtotime($date." +1day"));
    return $converteddate;
}

function getComments(){
    $comments = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){
        $comments = "<div class='each_comment'>There are no comments</div>";
    } else {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            $comments .= "<div class='each_comment'><small><em>".convert($row['comment_date'])."</em></small><br />".$row['comment']."</div>";
        }
    }
    return $comments;
    } 

function postComments($comment){
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($comment));
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (comment, comment_date ) VALUES ('".$comment."', now())");
    return true;
}
    if((isset($_GET['action'])) && ($_GET['action']== "post")){
        postComments($_POST['comment']);
    }
    echo getComments();
```

Thanks again for the help

Comment: The question isn't very clear.  What do you mean by "unique"?

Comment: @Roberto sorry what i mean, is that i have got it working for comment, i just dont know how to get it to work for comment1

Comment: Sorry my English is not the best

Comment: Am I understanding right, that you have 2 different pages (`'HTML'`) that shall save and get different types of comments (`'comment' and 'comment1'`)?

Comment: @Jeff yes :0 that is 100% it

Comment: So i got it working with comment for 1 page, now i need to get it to work with comment1 for the other page :)

Comment: @Jeff and that is were i am getting stuck on :)

Comment: I'll write you a quick answer...

Comment: @Jeff really appreciate the help , thanks xx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER*
For future visitors:
Don't copy this code, as it has several issues that go beyond answering the question.

What you need to add is an identifyer for the type of comment. (Type could be replaced with something more suitable to your case like 'product', 'user', ... whatever the difference is/what they are related to)

So in your database add that new column:

```
comments
--------
id
comment
type
comment_date
```

Now you need to pass around that type through all your calls, and it shall be specified in your 'HTML'-Page (which actually is php...).

```
<div class="comment_container">
  <div class="comments">
    <?php
        // specify the type needed on that page
        $type = 1;
        include_once("comments.php");
        echo getComments($type);
    ?>
  </div>
  <div class="comments_form">
    <table>
    <tr><td><textarea id="comment_text"></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="comment_process" value="Post Comment"/></td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
    // specify the type in javascript
    var type=1;
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#comment_process').click(function() {
        if ($('#comment_text').val() != "") {
                                         // add the type here:
            $.post("comments.php", {
                comment: $('#comment_text').val(),
                type: type,
                action: 'post'
            }, function(data) {
                $('.comments').html(data);
                $('#comment_text').val("");
            });
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

and in comments.php:

```
//....some code left out here
function getComments($type){
   $comments = "";
   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments where type=$type") or die(mysql_error());
   if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0){
       $comments = "<div class='each_comment'>There are no comments</div>";
   } else {
       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
           $comments .= "<div class='each_comment'><small><em>".convert($row['comment_date'])."</em></small><br />".$row['comment']."</div>";
       }
   }
   return $comments;
} 

function postComments($comment, $type){
   $comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($comment));
   $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments (comment, comment_date, type ) VALUES ('".$comment."', now(), ".$type.")");
return true;
}
if((isset($_POST['action'])) && ($_POST['action']== "post")){
    postComments($_POST['comment'], $_POST['type']);
    // send all the comments back to client
    echo getComments($_POST['type']);
}
// moved to html-file: echo getComments($type);
```

**NOTE**

There are several issues with that code.
First *don't use mysql functions*. For real. Unsecure and deprecated/deleted as of php7. Use mysqli or pdo. Furthermore your sql can be hacked with sql injection. Read about prepared statements.

The general structure of that code is not very good.
Try to seperate output and formating from getting data.
For example it would be much better if a function called 'getComments' only would get the comments from the database, then let others decide what to do with that data. The less one function does the better.
Please read about coding styles, maybe start learning object oriented programming.

I hope this still helps you to get a clue of where to go!

Comment: quick question, type is an int ? before i try this out

Comment: up vote for the disclaimer - haha.  Half the answers on SO should probably have one.

Comment: also sorry in the js file u said // add the type here:  so this line : $.post("comments.php?action=post&type="+type, does that mean the +type bit becomes +type1 +type2 +type3 etc etc? thanks

Comment: ah there is also an error on line 28 on php which is : postComments($_POST['comment'], $_POST['type']);

Comment: Ye cant seem to figre out this error on 28 , keeps saying Undefined index: type

Comment: yes, type is an int in my example, but you could change it to a string if better for your needs. No for the js-question: you don't need to change that to type1, 2, 3,... , because we've set the type above (that should change for every html page: `var type=1;` then `var type=2;` and so on

Comment: the error in line 28: change to `postComments($_POST['comment'].$_GET['type']);`. (read about post/get/put/ for further understanding)

Comment: I've changed the js and php code for that error again. leave it at $_POST, that's better (but you need to adjust the js as I did)

Comment: ah thanks jeff however now there are 2 more erros, Missing argument 2 for postComments() on : function postComments($comment, $type){ and Undefined variable: type on  $sql = mysql_query on line 24

Comment: Ok errors have been fixed, just copied ur new code down, however now i cant seem to post at all,

Comment: do you have `$type=1;` before `include('comments.php')` ? And reloaded the html file? - ok, seems to be fixed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107283/discussion-between-jeff-and-nevershow2016).

Comment: @Jeff i do have $type=1; on the php file before that but still nothing